# Sort a dict by numeric value of dict.values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict `d = {'a': '1', 'c': '10', 'b': '8', 'e': '11', 'g': '3', 'f': '2'}`. I want to sort the dict with numeric value of `d.values()`. Required ans is `['a','f', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'e']`. I had checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) . I couldn't make it to sort according to integer value of d.values().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'a': '1', 'c': '10', 'b': '8', 'e': '11', 'g': '3', 'f': '2'}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda i: int(d[i]))
['a', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the values in your dictionary are of type `string`: note the quotes around the numbers. Try setting your dictionary as:

```
d = {'a':1, 'c':10, 'b':8, 'e':11, 'g':3, 'f':2}
```